# Unity3D spotlight glitch on Samsung S6 and S7 edge

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, samsung-mobile

We are developing a motorbikes racing game under Unity 5.3.4p4 for Android.

I have a spotlight attached to a gameobject (the motorbike), the farther it is from the center of the world (0, 0) the more unstable/shaking it becomes when moving.  I've tested on many devices with different GPU and Android versions but this only happens in Samsung Galaxy Edge S6 and S7 devices (MALI GPU).

Does anyone has the same problem or know any solution for this?.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
After a lot of testing there seems to work fine only using Deferred instead of Forward rendering and enabling OpenGLES3, at least for the S7, the S6 has the same problem no matter what I do.
I've also tried downgrading to Unity 5.2.5 and upgrading to unity 5.3.5 without success.
As @Paul-Jan says, it seems it also affects iOS: https://community.unity.com/t5/Graphics/Problems-with-spotlight-on-mobile-precision-issue/td-p/2473711

Comment: Does galaxy s6 (not edge) work well?

Comment: @tim Unfortunately I don't have a Galaxy S6 not edge model to test, but looking at the hardware specifications it has the same Chipset, CPU & GPU as an edge model, so I guess it will behave the same way.

Comment: I am thinking what cause the problem is whether the phone itself or the edge screen?

Comment: This kind of error, the light glitchy, more and more as the object gets farther from the center of the world sounds like a GPU crunching the float values used to calculate it. I don't think the edge screen has anything to do with it because it should not make any difference in the light calculation or any other kind of CPU/GPU calculation related to lights in OpenGL and/or Unity. But of course a test would be needed to discard it.

Comment: @tim I have tested on a S6 not edge and it has the same problem.

Comment: This seems to be a problem on iOS as well: https://community.unity.com/t5/Graphics/Problems-with-spotlight-on-mobile-precision-issue/td-p/2473711 .